# Java jLayer application freezes while playing song

Tags: java, swing, jlayer

I have a problem with jLayer. I have a button with code for starting a song:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {        
    try {
        Player prehravac;
        FileInputStream buff = new FileInputStream(Okno.filename);
        prehravac = new Player(buff);
        prehravac.play();
        if (prehravac != null) {
            prehravac.close();
            this.dispose();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

When I click on this button, it begins to play the song but whole application freezes and I cannot click on anything. When the song ends, it's okay and I can click on other components again.

Can someone help me pls ? :) thank

Comment: it seems that is executed in the EDT so that's why freeze until song finish, try to do that with `SwingWorker`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because the song-playing happens in the same thread as the GUI, or more specifically the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Therefore, the GUI does not response, when the song is playing. To fix this, do something like this:

```
new Thread(){
  run(){
    //Your play code
  }
}.start();
```

This will play your stuff in a seperate Thread. However, you have to regard that since the GUI is responsive, you can start songs while songs are still playing.

For more information, see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Answer (score 2):

Tasks on the [`EDT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) *(event dispatch thread)* must finish quickly; if they don't, unhandled events back up and the user interface becomes unresponsive.